# Which files do I need to distribute from a C# build?

Tags: c#, .net, installation

When I build a C# application project named `MyApplication` with .NET 6.0 on Windows, I get the following files:

```
MyApplication.dll
MyApplication.exe
MyApplication.deps.json
MyApplication.dll.config
MyApplication.pdb
MyApplication.runtimeconfig.json
MyApplication.xml
```

Which of these files do I need to distribute?

**MyApplication.dll** contains the IL code of the application. I certainly need this one.

**MyApplication.exe** is the stub loader that starts the application. I do need this.

**MyApplication.pdb** contains the debug info. I don't need to distribute this.

But what about the others? They seem to contain some dependency information. But is that only required for the compiler, or is it required later at runtime? (My application consists of dozens of dll's).

Comment: You could do a smoke test by gradually deleting files from the output directory until `MyApplication.exe` does not start anymore.

Comment: I'd also include MyApplication.exe.config. Especially if you need/plan to use some runtime configuration options.

Comment: If you want to distribute application - you need to publish, not just build. dotnet publish has a brief description of those files you mentioned: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride Yea, I know I could try that, but when it comes to dependencies, it's likely to get wrong results, because it might work on one system and not on another, depending on what runtime version(s) are installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the spec of [runtime configuration files](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/rel/1.0.0/Documentation/specs/runtime-configuration-file.md)

> - MyApp.dll - The managed assembly for MyApp, including an ECMA-compliant entry point token.
> - MyApp.exe - A copy of the corehost.exe executable.
> - MyApp.runtimeconfig.json - An optional configuration file containing runtime configuration settings.
> - MyApp.deps.json - A list of dependencies, as well as compilation context data and compilation dependencies. Not technically required, but required to use the servicing or package cache/shared package install features.

So while the json files are not strictly required, I would probably recommend including them.

The `MyApplication.xml` is an optional documentation file that contains comments for your dll. This is probably not needed if you are distributing an application and not a library, and there should be an option to turn of the generation of this file in your project properties.

You should also check the documentation for [Deploying](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/) your application. I would especially consider the parts about [self contained](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/runtime-patch-selection) and [single file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview?tabs=cli) publishing.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. Self-contained or Single-file publishing is not really an option for me, since the actual application consists of several exes and a large number of libraries.